# DevExpress Create SUM of QTY in postings

Tags: devexpress

I'm trying to calculate the sum of Purchase postings on an Inventory Item.

I can't seem to find the right expression.
Can anyone give a hint ?

[Expression Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Pku.png)

Tried this formula in InventoryTransactions, but gets an error

[][[MovementType] == 'Creditor'].Sum([Qty])
(MovementType is a valid field in the file

Comment: Are MovementType and Qty fields defined on the same class ? Is that class (on the expression editor) the same as the selected object to get your calculation ?